# How to extract citations from a text (PHP)?

Tags: php, regex, quotations

**Hello!**

I would like to extract all citations from a text. Additionally, the name of the cited person should be extracted. [DayLife does this very well.](http://www.daylife.com/topic/Top_News/quotes)

**Example:**

> “They think it’s ‘game over,’ ” one senior administration official said.

The phrase *They think it's 'game over'* and the cited person *one senior administration official* should be extracted.

Do you think that's possible? You can only distinguish between citations and words in quotes if you check whether there's a cited person mentioned.

**Example:**

> “I think it is serious and it is deteriorating,” Admiral Mullen said Sunday on CNN’s “State of the Union” program.

The passage *State of the Union* is not a quotation. But how do you detect this? a) You check if there's a cited person mentioned. b) You count the blank spaces in the supposed quotation. If there are less than 3 blank spaces it won't be a quotation, right? I would prefer b) since there's not always a cited person named.

**How to start?**

I would first replace all types of quotes by a single type so that you'll have to check for only one quote mark later.

```
<?php
$text = '';
$quote_marks = array('“', '”', '„', '»', '«');
$text = str_replace($quote_marks, '"', $text);
?>
```

Then I would extract all phrases between quotation marks which contain more than 3 blank spaces:

```
<?php
function extract_quotations($text) {
   $result = preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $text, $found_quotations);
   if ($result == TRUE) {
      return $found_quotations;
      // check for count of blank spaces
   }
   return array();
}
?>
```

How could you improve this?

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Maybe $text = preg_replace('/([“”"\'»«])(.+?)\1/', '"\2"', $text);
Give us an exemple of input and desired output.

Comment: This sort of natural language parsing isn't likely to fit in a neat little function. It can quickly become extraordinarily complex if you want decent results.

Comment: @Havenard: The example is in the question yet. ;) See the paragraph "example". What should your code do? I don't understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ceejayoz already pointed out, this won't fit into a single function. What you're describing in your question (detecting grammatical function of a quote-escaped part of a sentence - i.e. “I think it is serious and it is deteriorating,” vs "State of the Union") would be best solved with a library that can break down natural language into tokens. I am not aware of any such library in PHP, but you can have a look at the project size of something you would use in python: http://www.nltk.org/

I think the best you can do is define a set of syntax rules that you verify manually. What about something like this:

```
abstract class QuotationExtractor {

    protected static $instances;

    public static function getAllPossibleQuotations($string) {
        $possibleQuotations = array();
        foreach (self::$instances as $instance) {
            $possibleQuotations = array_merge(
                $possibleQuotations,
                $instance->extractQuotations($string)
            );
        }
        return $possibleQuotations;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        self::$instances[] = $this;
    }

    public abstract function extractQuotations($string);

}

class RegexExtractor extends QuotationExtractor {

    protected $rules;

    public function extractQuotations($string) {
        $quotes = array();
        foreach ($this->rules as $rule) {
            preg_match_all($rule[0], $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
            foreach ($matches as $match) {
                $quotes[] = array(
                    'quote' => trim($match[$rule[1]]),
                    'cited' => trim($match[$rule[2]])
                );
            }
        }
        return $quotes;
    }

    public function addRule($regex, $quoteIndex, $authorIndex) {
        $this->rules[] = array($regex, $quoteIndex, $authorIndex);
    }

}

$regexExtractor = new RegexExtractor();
$regexExtractor->addRule('/"(.*?)[,.]?\h*"\h*said\h*(.*?)\./', 1, 2);
$regexExtractor->addRule('/"(.*?)\h*"(.*)said/', 1, 2);
$regexExtractor->addRule('/\.\h*(.*)(once)?\h*said[\-]*"(.*?)"/', 3, 1);

class AnotherExtractor extends Quot...
```

If you have a structure like the above you can run the same text through any/all of them and list the possible quotations to select the correct ones. I've run the code with this thread as input for testing and the result was:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["quote"]=>
    string(15) "Not necessarily"
    ["cited"]=>
    string(8) "ceejayoz"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["quote"]=>
    string(28) "They think it's `game over,'"
    ["cited"]=>
    string(34) "one senior administration official"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["quote"]=>
    string(46) "I think it is serious and it is deteriorating,"
    ["cited"]=>
    string(14) "Admiral Mullen"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["quote"]=>
    string(16) "Not necessarily,"
    ["cited"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it's written in PHP. I added the reference to nltk to demonstrate the complexity of doing it right.

Comment: Perfect! :) So I could possibly use it. How do I give an input to the function? And how do I call the function? And: Can I simply add my regular expressions for finding quotations in the addRule section?

Comment: You can copy-paste the code and add your own regular expressions with addRule(). But if you don't intend to add more complex extracting algorithms than regexes, you can just use the 3 regular expressions in the code with `preg_match_all()`. The rest is a nice OO-API that allows you to create other extractors - like one that does some parsing, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I've understood it. I'll ask for the "perfect regexes" in another question here. :)

Answer (score 3):

> If there are less than 3 blank spaces it won't be a quotation, right?

"Not necessarily," said ceejayoz.

> The passage State of the Union is not a quotation. But how do you detect this? a) You check if there's a cited person mentioned. b) You count the blank spaces in the supposed quotation. If there are less than 3 blank spaces it won't be a quotation, right? I would prefer b) since there's not always a cited person named.

b) doesn't even work for this very example - there are 3 blank spaces in "State of the Union".

Comment: "Not necessarily" Oh, yes of course, you're right. :) But USUALLY it won't be one. And if it is one, it USUALLY won't be important, will it?

b) could be increased to 4!?

Comment: @marco92w and "#LK$#@^" USUALLY won't be found in memory, so why don't we use it to delimit blocks in a cache?

Comment: I know that there will be some exceptions. But I needn't find ALL quotations. I would be glad if I could find 90% of them.

Answer (score 0):

A quotation will always have punctuation--either a comma at the end, to signify that the speaker's name or title is to follow, or the end of the sentence (.!?).

Comment: So will many non-quotations. `The President's annual address to Congress is called the "State of the Union".`

Comment: @ceejayoz: your quoted string didn't end in punctuation. The sentence containing it did. Quotations will have punctuation INSIDE the quotes.

Comment: Yes, I think that could help finding the quotations.

Comment: @Lucas Oman - In the United States, yes. In the Queen's English, puncutation only goes within the quotes if it makes logical sense to do so - if the punctuation doesn't apply to the quotation, it goes outside.

Comment: It's a pity. It wouldn't work for other languages, either. But the punctuation is just a part of it. You could easily implement the punctuation analysis for each language.